# Webgl how to handle drawing order in 3d

Tags: javascript, webgl, rendering

So I have started to implement 3d rendering in my engine, drawing a single cube works great. All faces are correctly rendering and depth check is on. The problem is that my rendering engine has a layer rendering system, their order is kept in an array that is looped through. So i place for example 10 3d boxes side by side on the same layer the camera wont know which one to render first.

[image]

Each 3d box is rendered separately from each other, and moving the camera doesnt change any rendering order. Depth test is enabled. Implementing a painters algorithm seems to be too taxing on the system, is there some way WebGL can handle this?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. How many cubes are you planning to draw? If you're trying to make a minecraft style system then AFAIK minecraft systems generally build meshes for each area (Say a 32x32x32 area). They look at the data for what cubes should be there and add faces wherever a face is needed (and don't add faces between 2 touching cubes since those faces would not be seen). In this way they only need 1 draw call per 32x32x32 area. Since users only add or remove one cube at a time they can easily update that area's mesh by just adding or removing a few faces.

Comment: Adding onto the confusion gman pointed out. You say that you're using depth testing but that isn't clear. Regardless of drawing order or even if they are instances of the same mesh it seems as though your depth testing isn't functioning correctly. Is your projection matrix calculating a depth value or are you not clearing the depth buffer between frames?

Comment: There's got to be something wrong with the way you're rendering them, because Z buffer should handle your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depth testing is how WebGL handles visibility. I'm not sure how you are handling it in your  engine but you may have made a mistake somewhere.

I've provided an example below that might put you on the right track.

```js
var sgl = function() {
 
 "use strict";
 
 var gl = null;
 var programs = [];
 var buffers = [];
 var textures = [];
 
 addEventListener("unload",function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < programs.length; ++i) {
   gl.deleteProgram(programs[i]);
  }
  
  for (var i = 0; i < buffers.length; ++i) {
   gl.deleteBuffer(buffers[i]);
  }
  
  for (var i = 0; i < textures.length; ++i) {
   gl.deleteTexture(textures[i]);
  }
  
  gl = null;
 });
 
 return {
  set ctx(_gl) {
   if (_gl instanceof WebGLRenderingContext) {
    gl = _gl;
   }
  },
  
  createProgram: function(vc,fc) {
   if (!gl) {
    return null;
   }
   
   var vs = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
   var fs = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
   
   gl.shaderSource(vs,vc);
   gl.shaderSource(fs,fc);
   gl.compileShader(vs);
   gl.compileShader(fs);
   
   try {
    if (!gl.getShaderParameter(vs,gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
     throw "VS: " + gl.getShaderInfoLog(vs);
    }
    
    if (!gl.getShaderParameter(fs,gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
     throw "FS: " + gl.getShaderInfoLog(fs);
    }
   } catch(log) {
    gl.deleteShader(vs);
    gl.deleteShader(fs);
    console.error(log);
   }
   
   var p = gl.createProgram();
   
   gl.attachShader(p,vs);
   gl.attachShader(p,fs);
   gl.linkProgram(p);
   gl.deleteShader(vs);
   gl.deleteShader(fs);
   
   programs.push(p);
   
   return p;
  },
  
  createIndexBuffer: function(d) {
   d = d instanceof Uint16Array ? d : new Uint16Array(d);
   
   var b = gl.createBuffer();
   
   gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,b);
   gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,d,gl.STATIC_DRAW);
   
   buffers.push(b);
   
   return b;
  },
  
  createVertexBuffer: function(d) {
   d = d instanceof Float32Array ? d : new Float32Array(d);
   
   var b = gl.createBuffer();
   
   gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,b);
   gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,d,gl.STATIC_DRAW);
   
   buffers.push(b);
   
   return b;
  },
  
  createTexture: function(pixels,width,height) {
   var t = gl.createTexture();
   
   gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
   gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D,t);
   gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D,gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,gl.NEAREST);
   gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D,gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,gl.NEAREST);
   gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D,gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S,gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
   gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D,gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T,gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
   gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D,0,gl.RGBA,width,height,0,gl.RGBA,gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE,pixels);
   
   textures.push(t);
   
   return t;
  }
 };
 
}();

void function() {
 
 "use strict";
 
 var canvasWidth = 180;
 var canvasHeight = 160;
 var canvas = null;
 var gl = null;
 
 var program = null;
 
 var uLightDir = null;
 var uModel = null;
 var uView = null;
 var uProj = null;
 var uTexture = null;
 
 var buffer = null;
 var texture = null;
 
 var modelMatrix = mat4.create();
 var viewMatrix = mat4.create();
 var projMatrix = mat4.perspective(
  mat4.create(),
  1.0472,
  canvasWidth / canvasHeight,
  1.0,
  100.0
 );
 
 var instances = [];
 var cameraAngle = 0.0;
 var cameraDistance = 15.0;
 var light = vec3.create();
 var camera = vec3.fromValues(0,0,5);
 var center = vec3.fromValues(0,0,0);
 var up = vec3.fromValues(0,1,0);
 
 onload = function() {
  canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  canvas.width = canvasWidth;
  canvas.height = canvasHeight;
  
  gl = canvas.getContext("webgl") || console.error("WebGL Not Supported.");
  
  sgl.ctx = gl;
  
  program = sgl.createProgram(`
   precision lowp float;
   
   const vec4 LIGHT_DIR = vec4(0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0);
   
   attribute vec3 aPosition;
   attribute vec3 aNormal;
   attribute vec2 aUV;
   
   varying float vDiffuse;
   varying vec2 vUV;
   
   uniform vec3 uLightDir;
   uniform mat4 uModel;
   uniform mat4 uView;
   uniform mat4 uProj;
   
   void main() {
    vUV = aUV;
    vDiffuse = max(0.4,dot(vec4(uLightDir,0.0),(uModel * vec4(aNormal,0.0))));
    gl_Position = uProj * uView * uModel * vec4(aPosition,1.0);
   }
  `,`
   precision lowp float;
   
   varying float vDiffuse;
   varying vec2 vUV;
   
   uniform sampler2D uTexture;
   
   void main() {
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(uTexture,vUV) * vDiffuse;
   }
  `);
  
  uLightDir = gl.getUniformLocation(program,"uLightDir");
  uModel = gl.getUniformLocation(program,"uModel");
  uView = gl.getUniformLocation(program,"uView");
  uProj = gl.getUniformLocation(program,"uProj");
  uTexture = gl.getUniformLocation(program,"uTexture");
  
  buffer = sgl.createVertexBuffer([
   // Position    Normal   UV
   
   // Front
    1.0, 1.0, 1.0,  0.0, 0.0, 1.0,  1.0,0.0,
   -1.0, 1.0, 1.0,  0.0, 0.0, 1.0,  0.0,0.0,
   -1.0,-1.0, 1.0,  0.0, 0.0, 1.0,  0.0,1.0,
   
   -1.0,-1.0, 1.0,  0.0, 0.0, 1.0,  0.0,1.0,
    1.0,-1.0, 1.0,  0.0, 0.0, 1.0,  1.0,1.0,
    1.0, 1.0, 1.0,  0.0, 0.0, 1.0,  1.0,0.0,
   
   // Back
   -1.0,-1.0,-1.0,  0.0, 0.0,-1.0,  1.0,0.0,
   -1.0, 1.0,-1.0,  0.0, 0.0,-1.0,  0.0,0.0,
    1.0, 1.0,-1.0,  0.0, 0.0,-1.0,  0.0,1.0,
   
    1.0, 1.0,-1.0,  0.0, 0.0,-1.0,  0.0,1.0,
    1.0,-1.0,-1.0,  0.0, 0.0,-1.0,  1.0,1.0,
   -1.0,-1.0,-1.0,  0.0, 0.0,-1.0,  1.0,0.0,
   
   // Left
   -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0,  0.0,0.0,
   -1.0,-1.0,-1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0,  1.0,1.0,
   -1.0,-1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0,  0.0,1.0,
   
   -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0,  0.0,0.0,
   -1.0, 1.0,-1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0,  1.0,0.0,
   -1.0,-1.0,-1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0,  1.0,1.0,
   
   // Right
    1.0,-1.0, 1.0,  1.0, 0.0, 0.0,  1.0,0.0,
    1.0,-1.0,-1.0,  1.0, 0.0, 0.0,  0.0,0.0,
    1.0, 1.0, 1.0,  1.0, 0.0, 0.0,  1.0,1.0,
   
    1.0,-1.0,-1.0,  1.0, 0.0, 0.0,  0.0,0.0,
    1.0, 1.0,-1.0,  1.0, 0.0, 0.0,  1.0,0.0,
    1.0, 1.0, 1.0,  1.0, 0.0, 0.0,  1.0,1.0,
   
   // Top
    1.0, 1.0,-1.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,  1.0,0.0,
   -1.0, 1.0,-1.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,  0.0,0.0,
    1.0, 1.0, 1.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,  1.0,1.0,
    
    1.0, 1.0, 1.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,  1.0,1.0,
   -1.0, 1.0,-1.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,  0.0,0.0,
   -1.0, 1.0, 1.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,  0.0,1.0,
   
   // Bottom
    1.0,-1.0, 1.0,  0.0,-1.0, 0.0,  1.0,1.0,
   -1.0,-1.0,-1.0,  0.0,-1.0, 0.0,  0.0,0.0,
    1.0,-1.0,-1.0,  0.0,-1.0, 0.0,  1.0,0.0,
   
   -1.0,-1.0, 1.0,  0.0,-1.0, 0.0,  0.0,1.0,
   -1.0,-1.0,-1.0,  0.0,-1.0, 0.0,  0.0,0.0,
    1.0,-1.0, 1.0,  0.0,-1.0, 0.0,  1.0,1.0
  ]);
  
  var width = 10;
  var height = 10;
  var pixels = new Uint8Array((width * height) << 2);
  
  for (var i = 0; i < pixels.length; i += 4) {
   var c = Math.random() < 0.5 ? 255 : 0;
   
   pixels[i + 0] = c;
   pixels[i + 1] = c;
   pixels[i + 2] = c;
   pixels[i + 3] = 255;
  }
  
  for (var x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
   var index = x << 2;
   
   pixels[index + 0] = 255;
   pixels[index + 1] = 255;
   pixels[index + 2] = 0;
   pixels[index + 3] = 255;
   
   index = (x + (height - 1) * width) << 2;
   
   pixels[index + 0] = 255;
   pixels[index + 1] = 255;
   pixels[index + 2] = 0;
   pixels[index + 3] = 255;
  }
  
  for (var y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
   var index = (y * width) << 2;
   
   pixels[index + 0] = 255;
   pixels[index + 1] = 255;
   pixels[index + 2] = 0;
   pixels[index + 3] = 255;
   
   index = ((width - 1) + y * width) << 2;
   
   pixels[index + 0] = 255;
   pixels[index + 1] = 255;
   pixels[index + 2] = 0;
   pixels[index + 3] = 255;
  }
  
  texture = sgl.createTexture(pixels,width,height);
  
  gl.useProgram(program);
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,buffer);
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(0,3,gl.FLOAT,false,32,0);
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(1,3,gl.FLOAT,false,32,12);
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(2,2,gl.FLOAT,false,32,24);
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(0);
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(1);
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(2);
  
  gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D,texture);
  
  gl.enable(gl.CULL_FACE);
  gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
  
  gl.clearColor(0.5,0.5,0.5,1.0);
  
  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(uModel,false,modelMatrix);
  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(uView,false,viewMatrix);
  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(uProj,false,projMatrix);
  
  var size = 5;
  var hSize = size >> 1;
  
  for (var x = -hSize << 1; x <= hSize << 1; x += 2) {
   for (var y = -hSize << 1; y <= hSize << 1; y += 2) {
    for (var z = -hSize << 1; z <= hSize << 1; z += 2) {
     if (Math.random() < 0.3) {
      instances.push(vec3.fromValues(x,y,z));
     }
    }
   }
  }
  
  loop();
 }
 
 function loop() {
  cameraAngle += 0.01;
  
  if (cameraAngle > 2.0 * Math.PI) {
   cameraAngle = 0.0;
  }
  
  camera[0] = Math.cos(cameraAngle) * cameraDistance;
  camera[1] = 1.0;
  camera[2] = Math.sin(cameraAngle) * cameraDistance;
  
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
  
  vec3.sub(light,camera,center);
  vec3.normalize(light,light);
  gl.uniform3fv(uLightDir,light);
  
  mat4.lookAt(viewMatrix,camera,center,up);
  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(uView,false,viewMatrix);
  
  for (var i = 0; i < instances.length; ++i) {
   mat4.fromTranslation(modelMatrix,instances[i]);
   gl.uniformMatrix4fv(uModel,false,modelMatrix);
   gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES,0,36);
  }
  
  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
 }
 
}();
```

```css
body {
 background-color: black;
}

canvas {
 display: block;
 margin: 30px auto 0px auto;
 border: solid 1px white;
 border-radius: 10px;
}

script {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
 </head>
 <body>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/toji/gl-matrix/8226d776/dist/gl-matrix-min.js"></script>
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
 </body>
</html>
```